# Extending $\widetilde{V}$ in order to obtain a partial isometry operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

Recall the following definition:

[image]

> I want to get a detailed proof of the following theorem. In particular the importance of extending $\widetilde{V}$.

[image]

Comment: yeah but $\operatorname{ran} T$ is a subset of $H$. it says 'into' not 'onto'! There is a square missing in the equation at $\lVert Tx \rVert$. The mapping $V$ is defined by $Vx = \widetilde{V}\pi x$, where $\pi$ is the orthogonal projection on $\overline{\operatorname{ran} P}$.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I don't understand what is the importance of extending $\tilde{V}$? Thanks.

Comment: i want to point out that you don't extend $\tilde{V}$ by continuity, which seems like you think because of item 1 of your question. The importance of $\tilde{V}$ is in defining the partial isometry $V$. Every partial isometry is in fact the product of an isometry on a subspace and an orthogonal projection.

Comment: I think there is something more fundamental which you don't understand. So explaining the proof without knowing what is your doubt seems pointless.
At that kind of proof, normally if you can formulate your confusion precisely, you already half solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A linear map $U:A\to B$ is called an isometry here whenever $\|Ua\|=\|a\|$ for all $a\in A$. Note that surjectivity is not imposed, so that $\tilde V:\mathrm{ran}(P)\to H$ is an isometry, and by continuity, so is its extension to the closure of $\mathrm{ran}(P)$.
   An important point to note is that $\tilde V$ is a *well defined* map, because whenever $Px=0$, we have $Tx=0$.
2. Since $H=\overline{\mathrm{ran}(P)} \oplus \mathrm{ran}(P)^\perp$, we can define $V(x+y)$ as $\lim_n\tilde V(x_n)$ for a sequence $x_n\to x$, where $x_n\in\mathrm{ran}(P)$ and $y\perp\mathrm{ran}(P)$. 
   Now its kernel is the second component, and it is an isometry restricted to the first component.

Comment: Please the second point is not clear to me.

Comment: Which part? Write $S$ for $\mathrm{ran} (P)$. So, $S\le H$, and we have $H=\bar S\oplus S^\perp$ (just as for any subspace). Now, we also have an isometry $S\to H$, and extend it to $H$ (by continuity on $\bar S$ and with zero on $S^\perp$) to obtain a partial isometry $H\to H$.

Comment: I don't understand what is the importance of extending $\widetilde{V}$? Thanks.

Comment: A partial isometry is an endomorphism (is of the form $H\to H$). The domain of $\tilde V$ is in general only a subspace of $H$, so we extend it.